How to gently but firmly approach someone about leading me on
So, long story short, I (man) was led on by a woman, let's call her Alice for convenience, over the course of about two months (In a previous revision I included a summary of the relationship, but I have since removed the summary because I cannot include all the details and it was leading users to comment on the course of action I have chosen rather than how I am executing the action). The fact Alice was not interested in a relationship and was leading me on was brought to my attention by her roommate. From what Alice and her roommate have said, Alice is struggling with multiple issues, and has turned to hooking up and alcohol to cope. Alice's roommate has said this is not the first time she has led someone on, and Alice is becoming a serial "heartbreaker", dropping the guys before they can get too close.
After finding this out, I was hurt by the rejection but more hurt by the deception and Alice not being truthful with me. Since then, I have had a few days to process and have reached the point where I can have compassion and pity for the struggle she is going through. Because of that I don't want to retaliate, but I do want to respect myself & not act like this didn't happen, and try to get her to understand there are consequences for her harmful actions. Thus I would like to gently but firmly confront her. With that in mind, I enjoy her company enough that I would possibly be open to friendship in the future. Additionally, I do not want to implicate the roommate and cause drama in their household.
As far as this course of action, I have several friends who I have informed of the details of my relationship with Alice and they support my decision to confront her in this manner. I have ruled out ghosting because we both frequent a location that I would like to continue to visit. I have also considered playing it cool and slowly beginning to distance myself from her, but that does not align with my goals.
So far I am thinking of something like this: "So, I've been thinking about some of the stuff you've said recently, reading between the lines, and I feel like I've been intentionally led on. I feel hurt and  disrespected, so I would like some space while [we are both at the previously mentioned location]."
My thoughts about the statement:

It seems far to brief, but I'm not sure how to expand it without adding details that could be a "vector of attack" for her to argue against. I also don't want to go into the details of how I read between the lines or what part of her story didn't make sense so that she can't figure out how to lie more effectively in the future.
I am focusing on I statements to avoid being accusatory and, similarly to the first point, not give her something to argue against. Since I will need to tell her this in a public place I want to have the lowest chance of the conversation escalating.
While I do have enough evidence from what I "should" know (i.e. stuff that I knew before her roommate talked to me) that I could have come to the conclusion Alice was leading me on, I am considering adding a scapegoat like "So, this weekend I was talking with a friend about our relationship and they pointed out some concerns, and long story short I feel like...". Weekend is specific because I last saw Alice and her roommate on Thursday, so the timeline wouldn't line up with me talking to the roommate. However, then I have an awkward transition from 'talking to a friend' to 'I' statements.

What are some ways I could improve this statement?

Can you spell out "Alice was not interested in a relationship," "led someone on," "heartbreaker," "I was hurt," "this didn't happen," and "her harmful actions"? The question does not say what leading on looked like, though the roommate is gossiping.

I excluded some of those details to avoid this being a vent/rant post, but if you think those details are relevant, than I will add them as footnotes.

If you resent her actions, maybe you'd want to walk away having dodged a bullet, not tell her off. Since she said she would like to keep it casual, that's not leading you on. But the relationship is strained.

Are you considering confronting the roommate, the biggest troublemaker of all?

At no point in your details about your relationship do I see anything I would count as lying or leading you on. Sounds like you (wanted to) read more into it than there was.

I believe that the roommate's motivations were to avoid me being hurt more, and to tell me the truth. I do not view the roommate as starting trouble.

I don't know very many women who, over a month or two, would actively cling to someone, sit with their legs across their lap, and rest their head on their shoulder, if they were not interested in them.

I have decided to remove information about Alice and my's relationship from the question. I have several friends who are more familiar with the situation agree that the course of action is reasonable, and adding the information has distracted from my goal of improving my statement to Alice.

"I don't know very many women who, over a month or two, would actively cling to someone, sit with their legs across their lap, and rest their head on their shoulder, if they were not interested in them." - But you hooked up, didn't you? Or did I misunderstand that?

Can you be clearer about "leading you on"? This usually means paying for dates, being nice, pretending to like the person, all because you're "on a promise" that you'll get sex out of it. And then when you don't, you're mad. That doesn't seem to be what happened here so what did you do that you otherwise wouldn't have, and what did you think you would get for that?

"I don't know very many women who, over a month or two, would actively cling to someone, sit with their legs across their lap, and rest their head on their shoulder" - I've known many women like this, who are friends or who are friends of my long-term partner, and are comfortable with our friendship. This may be a cultural difference. What culture is this?

@KateGregory that doesn't sound like a definition of "leading someone on".


I am focusing on I statements to avoid being accusatory and, similarly to the first point, not give her something to argue against.

This is a good approach, but I don't believe your current wording does this.

I've been thinking about some of the stuff you've said recently, reading between the lines, and I feel like I've been intentionally led on.

This document on "I Statements" says:

An “I-statement” focuses on your own feelings and experiences. It does not focus on your perspective of what the other person has done or failed to do

But how you are expressing it currently very much focusses on what you think the other person has done (deliberately led you on)
Instead you could say something like:

The way you behaved made me feel you had changed your mind" or "...you weren't serious about being casual.

Of course, this means you are being less accusatory (that's the point!) which may not be what you want. It sounds at the moment like you want to accuse her of leading you on and her not be able to argue back, but I don' think that's realistic when you make an accusation. If you talk about your feelings and not what she did or did not do, there is much less room for that; she cannot deny the feelings you experienced.

Not an answer with respect to improving the statement, per se, but this is how talking with Alice actually went. I used the statement in my question, she said she understands, and added that she had been meaning to clear the air. She apologized for being unclear with her intentions, especially in the last month, and ended her response by saying she was not trying to toy with my emotions.
For other readers who may be in similar situations, I am glad I reflected on this beforehand, for two reasons. First, I did not allow the original pain I felt guide my choice of words to extremes, as romantic feelings can do. Secondly, since I had processed my pain and empathized with her situation, in the moment I was ready to forgive her, and pre-meditating helped me remember that her situation does not excuse her actions, and holding a boundary will be healthier in the long run.
